# Understanding classes in ndb model - GAE

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore

I have database.py file which has a Class Parent(ndb.model) with different properties. What would happen if I pass Parent as the parameter to another class, such that

```
class child(Parent)
Pass
```

Can I define the properties of Parent in Class child, if I am Hard Coding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work, and child classes will inherit parent properties:

```
class Parent(ndb.Model):
    lastname = ndb.StringProperty()

class Child(Parent):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

Child(lastname='Doe', name='John').put()
```

You could have as many mix-ins and childs as you want, properties will be resolved correctly following language [python] rules.

Just keep in mind that only the actual saved entity will be in the datastore, `Child` in this example. In other words, only this `kind` will exist.

If you would like to query by the parent, to get all `Animals` for a canonical example, you would need to use a [PolyModel](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass).